# Consulta con eloquent cantidad y limite a obtener

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

Hola alguien podría ayudarme con una consulta eloquent.

```
User::with(['post','Y aun tengo más relaciones. ..'])
->where('nick',$nick)->first();
```

### de esta forma obtengo la información de un usuario X y veo  los posts.

pero necesito solo mostrar los últimos 5 post que hizo. podría usar OrderBy y take

### Pero necesito saber  La cantidad total de post que tiene ese usuario. podría usar `Count()`

podría hacerlo haciendo una consulta distinta, pero se que hay mejor forma de hacerlo.

podría hacerlo así . .  pero son muchas consultas, porque no solo  es eso. hay más cosas que necesito hacer.

```
Post::where('IDUSER',auth()->user()->id)->take(5)->get();
```

Y se que  a lo mejor hay una mejor forma de hacerlo, por al final lo enviare a un componente vue

Comment: solo necesitas saber los títulos de los últimos 5 posts de cada usuario? o solo necesitas sumar los ultimos 5 posts? es que no te entiendo

Comment: Creo que aquí está la clave para responder a tu pregunta: *por[que] al final lo enviare a un componente vue*.  ¿Qué vas a enviar al componente: sólo el total de posts, más datos como el título y el contenido de cada post... Sin responder a eso es imposible ofrecerte una forma optimizada de consultar a la BD.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes hacerlo de una manera super simple usando el método [`withCount()`](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) propio de las relaciones. Revisa la [documentación](https://laravel.com/docs/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models) respecto a este apartado.

> #### Contar modelos relacionados
>
> Si quieres contar el número de resultados de una relación sin tener
>   que cargar toda la relación en sí, tú puedes usar el método
>   `withCount`, el cual colocará una columna llamada `{relation}_count`
>   en tus modelos resultantes. Por ejemplo:
>
> ```php
> $posts = App\Post::withCount('comments')->get();
>
> foreach ($posts as $post) {
>     echo $post->comments_count;
> }
> ```

Entonces, aplicando esto a tu consulta:

```php
    $user = App\Post::withCount('posts')
        ->with(['relacion_1', 'relacion_2', 'posts' => function ($query) {
            $query->ordeBy("id", "desc")->limit(5);
        }])
        ->where('nick', $nick)
        ->first();
```

Entonces en tu vista (?) puedes acceder a este nuevo atributo así:

```html
<p> El usuario tiene {{ $user->posts_count }} publicaciones en total </p>
```

Además de poder acceder al resto de tus relaciones, incluída `posts`, como regularmente lo harías.